# Can't push docker image to gcloud

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gcloud

I'm following the [hello node Kubernetes tutorial](http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/)  but when I get to the step of pushing my machine to google cloud with the command:

`gcloud docker push gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/hello-node:v1`

I get the following error message:

`name invalid: Invalid repository name: gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/hello-node`

(Just do avoid double-checks, I replaced my PROJECT_ID with the actual number of the projecg)

I was able to push my image to a bucket, and run, but then my image doesn't show in Container Engine > Container Registry.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should replace `PROJECT_ID` with the alphanumeric ID of your project (e.g. "my-project-123").

Comment: Argh, lost my whole afternoon on this. I was using the number instead of the ID. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah it's confusing. Every GCP service should support the alphanumeric ID, but some also support the project number, which leads to moments like this :(